Save to audio file with OpenAL
I am using OpenTK, more precisely OpenAL. I am able to capture the sound from the mic, but then I want to save the data to a WAVE file.
I found a example how to write a wave file and the result is almost working.
I believe my file header is correct, but I have some doubt of the correct way to write the buffer data to the file.
I first tried recording with this settings:

44100 Hz
16 bits
2 channels

Playing the file was just some noise
I changed to a mono setting (1 channel).
This time I was able to reproduce the audio, but it was played 2 times faster
Is it possible that I should first transform the data from ALC.CaptureSamples before writing them directly to the stream ?
To add some code, first I have the capture samples, that I think work correctly (I got from the TestUnit from OpenAL repo):
int totalSamples = 0;
while (totalSamples < buffer.Length && !_cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
{
  int samplesAvailable = ALC.GetInteger(_captureDevice, AlcGetInteger.CaptureSamples);
  if (samplesAvailable < 512) continue;
  int samplesToRead = Math.Min(samplesAvailable, buffer.Length - totalSamples);
  ALC.CaptureSamples(_captureDevice, ref buffer[totalSamples], samplesToRead);
  totalSamples += samplesToRead;
  spinWait.SpinOnce();
}

And then I write to the stream simply:
// headers writing...
// ...
sw.Write(buffer, 0, totalSamples);

I don't find any sample about OpenAL and file writing...
Is everything correct ?
Am I missing some steps ?

For ease, I would try to get things working with just a single audio channels to begin with. I would also make sure you have a working example of writing a test tone to a .wav file before trying to grab data from any audio inputs.

Tried comparing with audio recorded from Audacity.
Headers are correct, but from my code data are 2 times smaller.
So I suppose I should do some transformation of my OpenAL buffer before send it to the file. But no info found...

Data of half the size suggests 1 channel is perhaps not being written as expected. Once you have a mono test tone, try and write a stereo .wav with tones of different frequencies in each channel. If the data is half the size, and garbled, and different in both channels in audacity, then that suggests the full sample values are not being written (e.g. only 8-bits of a 16-bit sample /  16-bits of a 32-bit frame)

OK @fdcpp gave me an hint with not full samples being written. So to make it working, for a mono 16bit sound, the buffer should be ushort and not byte type.
There are some missing knowledge about sound audio specs from my side 
So the specific parts of code are:
// Capture the device
_captureDevice = ALC.CaptureOpenDevice(null, 44100, ALFormat.Mono16, 1024);
...
// Start recording
var buffer = new ushort[44100 * 16];
...
// Writing data
ushort bytePerBloc = 1 * (16 / 8);
using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new())
using (BinaryWriter sw = new(memoryStream))
{
  sw.Write(['R', 'I', 'F', 'F']);
  sw.Write(totalSamples * bytePerBloc + 36);
  ...
  sw.Write(['d', 'a', 't', 'a']);
  sw.Write(totalSamples * bytePerBloc); // size of buffer

  for (int i = 0; i < totalSamples; i++)
  {
    sw.Write(buffer[i]);
  }
...
}

And now it's working.
Next step to try the same with stereo 16bits 
